# R JRI: trying to create data.frames from Java using REXP.createDataFrame

Tags: java, r, rjava, jri

I'm trying to create a data frame in R taking the data from an ArrayList in Java.

The code below seems to be the official JRI test suite ([see this link](http://www.rforge.net/DATRAS/files/org/rosuda/REngine/JRI/test/RTest.java)) however it doesn't even compile, for example in the first statement RList doesn't have a put method and REXP.createDataFrame method doesn't exist.

Is there any updated example of `REXP.createDataFrame`? Couldn't find a concrete/functional example online. Also, couldn't find any JRI documentation.

```
     String[] Rargs = {"--vanilla"};
     Rengine re = new Rengine(Rargs, false, null);

     if (!re.waitForR()) {
         System.out.println("Cannot load R");
         return;
     }

     RList l = new RList();
     l.put("a",new REXPInteger(new int[] { 0,1,2,3}));
     l.put("b",new REXPDouble(new double[] { 0.5,1.2,2.3,3.0}));

     re.assign("z", REXP.createDataFrame(l));

     REXP x = re.parseAndEval("z");
     System.out.println("  z = " + x);
```

**UPDATE**

I found out that there are two `REXP` classes `org.rosuda.JRI.REXP` and  `org.rosuda.REngine.REXP`, the latter has the method `createDataFrame(l)`, however the assignment doesn't work.  How to assing a data frame to an R variable?

Comment: Have you noticed that there is no "put" method in "org.rosuda.JRI.RList"?

Comment: Look at the link I posted and export the same libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it helps: my solution to create a data frame with JRI-REngine gives some thing like this:

```
    String[] dummyArgs = {"--vanilla"};
    REngine eng = REngine.engineForClass("org.rosuda.REngine.JRI.JRIEngine", dummyArgs, new REngineStdOutput (), false); // debug mode, print R-trace in Java

    String[] colNames = {"col1", "col2", "col3"};
    String[] col1 = {"a1", "a2", "a3", "a4"};
    String[] col2 = {"b1", "b2", "b3", "b4"};
    int[] col3 = {1, 2, 3, 4};

    REXP mydf = REXP
                .createDataFrame(new RList(
                        new REXP[] {
                                new REXPString(col1),
                                new REXPString(col2),
                                new REXPInteger(col3)},
                        colNames));

    eng.assign("myDataFrame", mydf);

    eng.parseAndEval("print(myDataFrame)");
```

In eclipse console :

`col1 col2 col3
1   a1   b1    1
2   a2   b2    2
3   a3   b3    3
4   a4   b4    4`